# Removing zero rows in a 3D matrix in MATLAB using any()

Tags: matlab, matrix, row, zero

Previously I used this line to remove zero rows in a regular matrix:

```
RV = RV(any(RV,2),:);
```

But I did the following for a 3D matrix. I still want to remove zero ROWS:

```
RV = RV(any(RV,2),:,:);
```

But I get a warning that says 'Index exceeds matrix dimensions'. What did I do wrong?

Comment: check the value of any(RV,2) and you will get your answer. Its a 3-D array so thats why you get the above error.

Comment: Also note that it will not be possible to remove a row from a particular page of a 3D matrix since each MxN page must be the same size.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what you can possibly do for 3-D arrays:

```
x=squeeze(any(RV,2));
[row,dimension]=find(x==0);
```

Now again this is a 3-D array, you just can't remove `ith` row from `jth` dimension. If you want to do that, then save it into a cell array or 3 different 2-D arrays.